# Add get image URL; within JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm customizing an awesome plugin allowing easy declared cue points for an HTML5 Video. (It's called cuepoint.js)

It came stock with declared variables; and once those variables are triggered / it displays the text in the form of a caption on the screen. Which is fine; BUT I would like to figure out how to call images within the code already written.

I've tried squeezing a `getElementbyID` and the standard HTML `img` tag, as well as get a `#div` but it's not rendering. Any pointers at using this same code and calling images; as opposed to text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Slides object with a time (integer) and a html string
var slides = {
0: "I would like to display an Image here, though",
2: "This is 2 Seconds.",
3: "This is 3 Seconds.",
6: "This is what 6 Seconds looks like.",
10: "This is 10 Seconds.",
}
```

Comment: so you want that instead of the text a image is displayed?

Comment: What do you get when you inspect the div.subtitle?

Comment: adding <img src="image.jpg"> should work. It's in the documentation.

Comment: Nothing appears; and it breaks the functionality of cuepoints. I tried; 0: <img src="http://bytes.com/images/default_avatar.jpg">, as well as within quotations. Suggestions?

Comment: yes you would need quotes around the <img>. The source path of your image is wrong. it should start with http://

Comment: Yes. I've tried that as well. Thanks for your help. It seems the 'http: // ' (Back slashes, comment out the rest of the line; making it not read)

Comment: Have you tried some simpler HTML yet, like perhaps a bold tag to see if the issue is with your image tag specifically or the general HTML handling?

Comment: @1977: How are you adding the image?  It should be like this: `0: '<img src="http://example.com/cool.png" />',`.  The slashes aren't a comment.

Comment: AH - this did it! I hadn't tried single quotes and the />. Thanks Rocket; if you wanted to add that syntax as your answer; I will accept. Cheers for the help all!

Comment: Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/QGBPF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want HTML to appear as a slide, just add that HTML as a string.

```
var slides = {
  0: "<img src='http://example.com/image.jpg' />",
  2: "This is 2 Seconds.",
  3: "This is 3 Seconds.",
  6: "This is what 6 Seconds looks like.",
  10: "This is 10 Seconds."
}
```